# Loading a CSV file into Neo4J running in Docker

Tags: csv, docker, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I have Neo4J running in Docker (Windows 10). I want to import a large CSV file into it, using Node and `neo4j-driver`.

My query is (limited to 5 rows, for testing purposes):

```
let csvPath = 'file:///C:/Users/Test/largefile.csv';

let query = `
  USING PERIODIC COMMIT
  LOAD CSV FROM '${csvPath}' AS line
  WITH line LIMIT 5
  MERGE (:Person {name: line[1]})-[:connected_to]->(:Person {name: line[2]})
`;
```

No matter what I try to put in the path, the driver keeps looking for `file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/C:/Users/Test/largefile.csv`.

I tried with/without drive letter; tried local file and using `./`; tried diffrent paths - the driver always looks for the file at `/var/lib/neo4j/import` even though I have no such folder on my machine.

Is it possible to import the file from my host machine, or will I need to copy it into the Docker container, into that folder structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to copy it into the docker container or into a directory that is mapped into it; Neo4J by default only supports loading CSV from its `import` directory, and all LOAD CSV paths will be relative to that.

This is with the out-of-the-box options; by modifying the `dbms.directories.import` variable in the config file, this can be changed, but it is explicitly not recommended by Neo4J documentation.